# Angular js node js sql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

i have  a angular js  node js app in that app user can select table name field name operator value from dropdown in that time a sql query will generate and that query needto show on front end ui  im giving an image the fllowing example what exact result i want is  Select count(*) from User, LoginEventStream, Account,,,, where LoginEventStream.USERID = User.Id and Account.Name = abc......etc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt47S.png)

```
 <table class="table  table-bordered col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-6 mr-4 ">
                            <thead style="background: #fbb040" >
                              <tr class="text-white text-center shadow-none " >
                                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Table name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Field</th>
                                <th scope="col">Operator</th>
                                <th scope="col">Value</th>
                                <th scope="col">Add Row</th>
                                <th scope="col">Remove</th>
                                
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" >
                                <td class="text-center" >
                                    
                                    {{row.id}}
                                </td>
                            <div ng-repeat="tableField in row.operator" >
                                {{tableField}}
                            </div>
                                <td class="text-center" >
                                    <select ng--model="row.tablename"  ng-options=" x as x.object_name for x in tables |limitTo:3500" >
                                        <option value=''>- Please Choose Table name -</option>
                                    </select>
                                  <span ng-if="selectFieldValidation" class="text-center" style="color:red; margin-top:10px;" >Please Select One valid Field</span>
                                </td>
                               
                                <td class="text-center" >
                                    <select ng-model="row.fieldname" ng-options="field as field.field_name for field in fieldname |limitTo:3000" >
                                        <option value=''>- Please Choose Fieldname -</option>
                                    </select>
                                  <span ng-if="selectFieldValidation" class="text-center" style="color:red; margin-top:10px;" >Please Select One valid Field</span>
                                </td>
                                
                                <td><select  ng-model="row.operator"   ng-required="true" >
                                    <option value="" selected >Please select</option>
                                    <option    value="=" >Equal to</option>
                                    <option    value=">" >Greater than</option>
                                   
                                    <option    value=">=" >Less than or equal to</option>
                                    <option    value=">" >Greater than or equal to</option>
                                    <option    value=">" >Less than or equal to</option>
                                  
                               
                                  </select>
                                  <span ng-if="selectOperatorValidation" style="color:red; text-align:left;" >Please select an operator</span>
                                </td>
                                  
                                  <td class="text-center">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="row.value"  placeholder="" style="width:200px;" >
                                    <span ng-if="selectValue" style="color:red; text-align:left;" >Plese Enter some value</span>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="text-center" >
                                    
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle " style="font-size: 30px;" ng-click="addRow()" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                  </td>
                           
                                  <td class="text-center" >
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="row.id ==1" ng-click="removeRow(row.id)"disabled ><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="row.id ==2" ng-click="removeRow(row.id)"disabled ><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="row.id > 2" ng-click="removeRow(row.id)" ><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                  </td>

                                 
                                
                              </tr>
                              
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                         
                      <!-- <div class="col-md-4 mt-3 mb-3 row d-flex justify-content-between" >
                       <a href=""   ng-click="addRow()" >Add Row</a>
                       
                      </div> -->
                      <!-- <div class="media mb-3" ng-if="buttonState == false" >
                        <img class="align-self-start mr-3" width="20px" />
                        <div class="media-body0">
                            <button class="btn costom_btn" ng-click="submitForm()" >Activate & Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media mb-3" ng-if="buttonState == true" >
                        <img class="align-self-start mr-3" width="20px" />
                        <div class="media-body0">
                            <button class="btn costom_btn" ng-click="submitForm()" disabled>Activate & Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div> -->

                    <div class=" col-md-12 row mt-4 d-flex flex-row " >
                        <div class=" col-md-2 col-md-2 mt-2 mr-3 " >
                            <p>Criteria Logic :</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-10 mt-2  "   >
                            <div class="d-flex d-flex-row"  >
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:16; color:black; margin-right: 10; " >  Select count(*) from</p> <p class="text-center" style="font-size:16; font-weight: bold; color: black; margin-left: 14px; " ng-repeat="x in rows" > {{x.tablename.object_name}}</p> <p class="text-center" style="font-size:16; color:black; font-weight:bold;margin-left:14px;" >Where</p>
                                <p ng-repeat="value in rows" >{{ value.fieldname.fieldname }}</p><p ng-repeat="value in rows" >value</p> <p ng-repeat="value in rows" >{{ value.value }}</p>
                              
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse" >
                          
                           <button class="btn btn-danger ml-3 "  >Cancle</button>
                           <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm()"  >Save</button>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: ok i qill give  you the code snippet

Comment: hellow sir please check my post i have aded code  on that

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i need to generate a query Select count(*) from User, LoginEventStream, Account,,,, where LoginEventStream.USERID = User.Id and Account.Name = abc......etc like this to show in ui

Comment: here the tablename fieldoparator and value comes frm the html table

Comment: What I mean actually is the query that I want to show will be hard coded , like SQL count () from (table name that I'm shown in table name drop down user can select from that and show on quey sentence) (field name same as table name) oparator same as firldynamr  value user could be type

Comment: Now what I made is  my query also genarated but but the format is wrong

Comment: U understand what I actually mean sir

Comment: Edit the question and don't add additional information in comments. Also take your time and write full sentences, I still don't get what you actually mean. Proofread your text and write it in a way that is easy to understand.